# Wicket 7 - Select, SelectOptions and pre-set

Tags: wicket, dropdownchoice

Im using Select instead of DropDownChoice to use OPTGROUP.

```
Select<Role> roleInput = new Select<Role>("role", new PropertyModel<Role>(this,"selectedRole"));
```

The two list of Role are:

```
SelectOptions<Role> fedOptions = new SelectOptions<Role>("federazione",federationRoleList,new RoleRenderer());
SelectOptions<Role> eOptions = new SelectOptions<Role>("enti",eRoleList,new RoleRenderer());
```

Its working well when submitting and also applying a  AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior on roleInput, I have my PropertyModel dynamically modified.

Unfortunally I have a problem with pre-set.
I tried to set selectedRole with a specific Role but the Select always start with the first element of the first list.

DropDownChoice works perfectly pre-setting the model but not Select.

I've tried with

```
roleInput.setModelObject(selectedRole);
```

but its not working.

I thinks the problem is with this component that has to manage two or more Repeaters instead of a single list.

Any clue?

Thanks

EDIT:
Implementation of RoleRenderer

```
public class RoleRenderer implements IChoiceRenderer<Role>,Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Object getDisplayValue(Role object) {
    return object.getName();
}

@Override
public String getIdValue(Role object, int index) {
    return object.getId().toString();
}

@Override
public Role getObject(String id, IModel<? extends List<? extends Role>> choices) {
    return getObjectFromId(id);
}

public Role getObjectFromId(String id){
    return null;
};
```

}

NOTE: getObjectFromId require access to Manager so will be overrided outside.

Comment: Please, can you post your implementation of RoleRenderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.SelectOption#onComponentTag() and see what is returned by `select.isSelected(this)` for the SelectionOption that matches the default model (object).
It might be that your `#equals()` implementation is not correct.